# Updates on live server without using Control Panel

Tags: craft3, updates, cli

I'll freely admit to being a bit of a newb when it comes to SSH but wanting to start utilizing it more for my Craft3 sites. Maybe this is an irrelevant question but is it possible to update craft on the live server through ssh?

I'm ssh'd into my server and tried `./craft update all` but I keep getting `Permission denied`.

`composer update` works fine though. Am I making a mistake or is it more of a hosting configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to `chmod +x craft` on the `craft` executable so it an execute: https://askubuntu.com/questions/443789/what-does-chmod-x-filename-do-and-how-do-i-use-it/443799